# Column inside GridView Overflowing in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-column

The column inside the gridview is overflowing in each and every item of the grid view, and I do not understand what is going on in here.

```
Expanded(
                child: GridView.builder(
              itemCount: 4,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2, mainAxisExtent: 150, mainAxisSpacing: 20),
              itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                return Recommendations();
              },
            ))


// Recommendations Section
class Recommendations extends StatelessWidget {
  const Recommendations({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 180,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black12,
            blurRadius: 2,
            spreadRadius: 1,
          )
        ],
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                width: 180,
                height: 180,
                child: Text(""),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Powerfule am",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Rs. 24,000",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text("Learn More", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
                minimumSize: Size.zero,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                elevation: 0,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

I can do it while using a listview and row but it would not be optimal, and I think there would be be better solutions than this.

[image]

I hope you can help me with this one.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

**To fix this issue, you can wrap the Column inside an Expanded widget. This will allow the Column to take up the available height inside the Container**

```
class Recommendations extends StatelessWidget {
  const Recommendations({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 180,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black12,
            blurRadius: 2,
            spreadRadius: 1,
          )
        ],
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                width: 180,
                height: 180,
                child: Text(""),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Powerfule am",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Rs. 24,000",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("Learn More", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
                      minimumSize: Size.zero,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                      elevation: 0,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```